# What is the size of objects for this class?

Tags: c++

```
Class Time{ 
int hour, min, sec; 
Time(){}; 
Time(int h,int m, int s){ 
hour = h; 
min = m; 
sec = s; 
} 
void printTime(){ 
cout<<hr<<”:”<<min<<”:”<<sec; 
} 
}
```

I just want to know what is the size of objects in this class ?

Comment: cout << sizeof(Time);

Comment: 'sizeof Time' will tell you. You don't need to ask other people.

Comment: The size of `int` depends on the platform; there is a minimum range that an `int` has to support but no maximum size.  The size of a class may not be the sum of the member sizes, as the compiler is allowed to add padding for alignment.

Comment: And note that the answer is specific to the platform, compiler, compiler flags, surrounding #pragmas, etc etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
Time timeObject;
int size = sizeof(timeObject);
```